# Constexpr typedef

Tags: c++, typedef, constexpr

Unfortunately you can not do something like this:

```
typedef constexpr int cint;
```

And that is not the end of the world....just have to type out the extra 9 (10 if you include the space) characters every time you need to use `constexpr`.

But I have created a class and I want to *only* be able to create constexpr versions of this class (using a non `constexpr` version would not make any sense).

So my plan was to create the class with a non accessible namespace, and then  create in my main namespace a `constexpr` typedef, like so:

```
namespace MainNameSpace{
  namespace detail{
    class MyClass{};

  }
  typedef constexpr detail::MyClass MyClass;
}
```

Unfortunately I discovered that this cannot be done....is there any way to achieve a similar effect (with out using macros)?

Comment: `constexpr` isn't part of the type system. It's part of the *expression* system, i.e. of the nature of *values*.

Comment: @KerrekSB I discovered that the hard way

Comment: `using a non constexpr version would not make any sense` How does a constexpr version make sense? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @deviantfan I have designed a class specifically for compile time strings...if I wanted to use the non-`constexpr` version I was probably trying to use a normal string or I just forgot to type it out.....I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this mistake

Comment: @DarthRubik: "*if I wanted to use the non-constexpr version I was probably trying to use a normal string*" Why? A static string would presumably not allocate heap space. That sounds like a good reason to want to use one even at runtime, where reasonable.

Comment: @NicolBolas I only call it `StaticString` because it *can* be used with `constexpr`....but it uses a **ton** of recursion, which is a good reason to not use it at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef constexpr detail::MyClass MyClass;` doesn't make much sense. You're establishing a contract that `MyClass` is a valid `constexpr` class and that you will only use it in `constexpr` contexts, but there is no way the compiler can guarantee that by that statement alone...it all comes down to how `MyClass` is implemented and what contexts you use it in. It's redundant and meaningless. If you're interested in a "compile-time string class", take a look at [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view).

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible in C++20 with [consteval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) specifier.

I can't run a test yet but I think that you could either write *immediate constructors* in `MyClass` or write an *immediate function* which create an instance of `MyClass` as constant expression only.

```cpp
//immediate constructors
class MyClass {
    consteval MyClass();
    consteval MyClass(const MyClass&);
};

//OR immediate instantation function
consteval MyClass make_myclass();
```